# Two request submitted for single request

Tags: java, servlets, struts2, static-methods, struts-action

I have a static method inside a Class as shown below:

```
class A {
    public static addInfo(Temp t) {
       // .....some calculation code here....
       // .....then data from Temp object t is added to database.
    }
}
```

Temp is an Entity class.

I have an Action from where I call this static `addInfo()` method:

```
public class Test implements ServletRequestAware, ServletResponseAware {
      Temp t = new Temp();
      //.....add data to Temp Object.....
      A.addInfo(t);
}
```

Here Temp object contains unique data for each request. But sometimes the same Request is added more than one time in database. What can be the reason?

Comment: Are you sure everytime you are getting unique data from request.. I mea the data you pass form or coming from data is unique ?

Comment: S2 action is not exactly a servlet. Show method where do you call `addInfo` and action configuration.

Comment: Sometimes uses press F5 just to be sure if they still logged in and press OK if the dialog appears asking to send the data submitted.

Comment: Without code and/or configs it's impossible to help. S2 won't arbitrarily run requests twice.

Comment: User makes a doubleclick on the submit button, maybe.